# Will I be able to use Win 8 drivers?

Tags: drivers

Will I be able to use windows 8 drivers on this OS or will I need to find different one to make stuff such as my killer wireless card and display work?

I have a killer wireless 1202 with bluetooth and I really need to know if this will work or not plus I need to know if I will be able to use Google drive or skydive

Answer (score 5):

You can't use Windows drivers on Ubuntu.  You probably won't need drivers depending on your hardware.  I would recommend that you try Ubuntu before installing that way you'll know if all hardware works OK.

Boot from the Ubuntu CD/DVD or bootable USB, and choose try Ubuntu.

[image]